# Where to get mac ISO for VirtualBox

Tags: mac, virtualbox

I've got a Mac Pro running Catalina. I'd like to run a guest also running Catalina. Where do I find an ISO so I can do that?

Comment: https://archive.org/details/OsxLeopardInstall If it's not legit, it's not my fault. Link provided without warranty

Comment: Duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128319/official-way-to-obtain-an-os-x-iso-file. Apple questions get more love on the Apple StackExchange anyway :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128319/official-way-to-obtain-an-os-x-iso-file

I didn't test it, but, as far as I know, the method given there should still work on Catalina.